# Pass a comment id through url and append the comment post's slug in the url

Tags: url-rewriting

Here's the scenario:
I wrote a custom url rule to pass a comment id to a template and display the comment and comment meta as a single page (`eg. http://example.com/reply/56`) and it works fine. But now I'm trying to refine this rule to include the comments post slug in the URL. So when I visit `'http://example.com/reply/56'` it should map to `'http://example.com/the-post/reply/56'`. I'm actually stuck at this point. Here's what I've done till now:
The rule that works:

```
<?php 
add_rewrite_rule( '^reply/(.*)?$', 'index.php?pagename=reply-page&reply_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );
?>
```

Added a `query_var` `'reply_id'` for this.

Now the code I'm trying:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'test');
function test()
{
    $reply_struct = '/reply/%reply_id%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%reply_id%', '([^/]+)', 'reply_id=$matches[1]');
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('reply_id', $reply_struct, false);
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'reply_permalink', 10, 3)
function reply_permalink()
{
    $rewritecode= array(
        '%reply_id%'
    );

    $test = '';
    if ( strpos($permalink, '%reply_id%') !== false ) 
    {
        $i = get_query_var('reply_id'); //Trying to get the comment id, this is where I'll get the post slug and append it to the url
        $test = 'test';
     }

     $rewritereplace = array(
       $test
     );
     $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
     return $permalink;
}
```

I think when I access the URL `'http://example.com/reply/56'`, I should get `'http://example.com/test/'` or `'http://example.com/reply/test'`. But I'm not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you declare `$wp_rewrite` as a global in your test function, you'll be trying to access the local variable `$wp_rewrite`.  This, of course, won't work.

Add the line `global $wp_rewrite;`:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'test');
function test()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $reply_struct = '/reply/%reply_id%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%reply_id%', '([^/]+)', 'reply_id=$matches[1]');
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('reply_id', $reply_struct, false);
}
```